# Continue text below forced \pagebreak in longtable

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I have a long table that I would like to break up in certain chunks of different sizes. If I use a \pagebreak to break the longtable before the end of the page, the remainder of the page remains blank, and the text only continues at the end of the longtable.

Is it possible to continue the text below the first part(s) of the table?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}    

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lr}
\caption{A sample long table}\\
\hline
Left&Right\\
\hline
\endhead
1&4\\*
5&2\\*
\pagebreak
9&3
\end{longtable}
\lipsum{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: short answer: no, not really.

Comment: you need to split your longtable to multiple tabular and use `\begin{table}[t]`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I was afraid it wouldn't be possible. In the end, I just split the long table into shorter tables and decreased the table counter accordingly.